# CDatabase OpenEx - timeout

Tags: sql-server, timeout

I have a C++ program using the MFC CDatabase class.

When I try to connect to a SQL Server, I want the program to timeout if it can't find the server. But calling SetLoginTimeout does not seem to help - I get the exception after 10 seconds or so, regardless of the login timeout I pass to SetLoginTimeout.

```
CDatabase   *m_pDB
m_pDB=new CDatabase();
m_pDB->SetLoginTimeout ( 1 );
strConstring = {"Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerXXX;Database=SomeDB;Uid=SomeUser;Pwd=abcd;"

m_pDB->OpenEx(strConstring,CDatabase::noOdbcDialog) ;
```

I tried to specify a timeout in the connection string but that did not work either:

```
strConstring = {"Driver={SQL Server};Server=ServerXXX;Database=SomeDB;Uid=SomeUser;Pwd=abcd;Connection Timeout=1"
```

Why is that?

Comment: Just wondering if you ever found a resolution to this? If so, would you mind sharing it here?

Comment: No, I am afraid I did not.